# Android Back Button reacts too quickly

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android application and when I press the back button from my device (normal press time for a person, 1 second or less), it skips from my activity, to the previous activity (menu) and then exits the application.
But if I tap the back button quickly, it reacts as expected, it goes to the menu.
I've tried to find a solution but no success.
I've always tried to override the back button default behavior but no success either.
Is there a way to set a reaction time for the back button to react?

Many thanks in advance!

P.S.- I have other activities that maintains the expected behavior in back button when pressed  with a normal press time.

Comment: Could you please post the code where you handle back-presses?

Comment: That's the thing, I am not handling the back key press since the back button has the default behavior I want it to have.

Comment: Could you show us the code part where you start your activites then? Have you tested this behaviour on other devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was developing an extra option for an application that already exists, and I found out that I should extend **not** from the Activity from Android but an already extended Activity called SEActivity. So in this extended version of Activity they override the method onKeyDown like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

By extending this SEActivity, the Back button works with the expected behavior.
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

"Is there a way to set a reaction time for the back button to react?"

Yes, you can simply record the time when the button is pressed and react differently in onBackPressed by calculating the (currentTime-lastTimePressed)

To allow this to work with previous activities, you can ask activities to startActivityForResult, so that when you finish your activity you can pass on the time as well to let them know if they should exit as well.

Comment: Why would anyone delay the response time from when the back-button is pressed to a action actually occurs? There is probably something wrong with the code, so encouraging to bad code and bad design is not nice.

Comment: This is not the best pattern out there. But I can def see cases where the one would want to know the time between two buttons gets pressed. Also, my understanding is that he wants to react differently base on button pressed times, NOT to delay the response time.

Comment: @Edison I actually wanted to delay the response time, since the back button on my current activity seems to make back not only on my activity but on the previous one (the menu in this case).
The hierarchy is **App > Menu > MyScreen**. When I click back on **MyScreen** it should only go back one level until **Menu**, but it actually goes to **App** and closes it, like if I pressed back on **Menu**, which I didn't.

Comment: I see, sorry I misinterpreted your question. How are you doing your navigation right now? If they are in the same activity, override onBackPressed should work, provided that you do the book keeping correctly.